Getting NewConnectionError while connecting with seleniumwire chrome on amazon EC2 instance
I am getting this error frequently not everytime.

HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=32817): Max retries exceeded
with url: /session/286f9b1508aa3fab78fee8a606577194/execute/sync
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
object at 0x7fd56e845400>: Failed to establish a new connection:
[Errno 111] Connection refused'))

When I send request again, it works. But doesn't work when I send subsequent requests.
What i am doing wrong.
I am using these Chrome options.
    proxies: dict = {
        "httpProxy": proxy_string
    }
    options.proxy = Proxy(proxies)

    # Other Chrome options
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")`

Using Chrome version as 126.0.6478.55
Please let me know if any further info required.
I have tried hitting request again and again. Sometimes its working and sometimes giving exception.
I am doing one thing here
@staticmethod
    def is_instance_valid(instance):
        try:
            instance.execute_script("return true;")
            logging.info("Browser instance is valid")
            return True
        except WebDriverException:
            logging.error("Browser instance is invalid")
            return False

Can this piece of code does this?
I am downloading chrome and driver version like this in my docker file.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 curl unzip \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Check Chrome installation
RUN echo google-chrome --version
RUN google-chrome --version | awk '{print $3}' > /tmp/chrome_version.txt

RUN wget -N "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.55/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip" -P /tmp

RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /tmp
RUN mv /tmp/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
   && chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
   && rm -rf /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip


looks like you're trying to execute script there... include the relevant code in your question.  (since the browser is refusing the connection it may be something prior to that call...) Also show initialization code.  You may also want to try first without options or setting proxy to see if one of these is causing an issue.

@browsermator i cant post whole code as its production code of company. But issue is not persistent its intermittently coming. any reason for this?

@browsermator have added one piece of code. can you check this.

One update on this. I was using chrome version as 126 earlier. But on 7th august google updated the stable version to 127. From that point it started behaving like this. How can i go back to version 126. As i cant check oldest version history in google. Right now i am fetching chrome in linux like above mentioned code.

it seems to be a bug that keeps coming back for chromedriver.  At some point the session is dropped.   There is a timeout for the session itself I think something triggers that.  I think by default it's pretty long... like 5 minutes so it can be triggered by an extremely slow response from a server... but it seems other things can also trigger it.  I've never seen this behavior with Geckodriver.

@browsermator so you are suggesting to use Geckodriver with google chrome instead of chromedriver? And can the google chrome version affect this or it doesnt matter? because chromedriver version didnt gets changed its the google chrome version which got updated.

You might try with geckodriver and Firefox just to rule out other possible causes.  It could definitely also be caused by the browser itself since that's handling the other end of the wire protocol.  If it stops responding, it will eventually trigger the session timeout.  This causes the browser to stay open since the driver can no longer tell it to shutdown. Are you seeing that behavior?

To give you further clues, this seemed to be triggered in the past (pre-100 versions) when driver methods that returned void or nothing were used.  Something about not waiting for returned results...  in your case if you assign a value to the results of the exceute_script, it should wait for a promise returned.  (there's a few others that return void... get() is one of them.)

also a part of the older bugs (which were fixed at some point but caused this same behavior) were other timeouts being thrown... (such as script timeout or pageload timeout... some assumptions were made that certain timeouts would be longer than others and that caused an issue)  For further testing make sure that Selenium version, driver version and browser version are all up to date, as that should be the most well tested cases at google.

@browsermator i have found the issue, actually i was using undetected_chrome of seleniumwire which was causing the issue. when i switched to chrome of seleniumwire issue got resolved. I dont know why undetected_chrome is not working. My requirement was to not get detected while scraping so i chose undetected_chrome.
